# How to pause cmd before it close?

Tags: c#, cmd

This is my code

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo proc = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
proc.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
proc.Arguments = "/C "+ "ipconfig" ;
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(proc);
```

when I run this code , Cmd run and shut down so quickly .
How to pause it ?

THANKS A LOT :)

Answer (score 6):

Specify the K parameter instead of C

From Microsoft documentation:

**/c : Carries out the command specified by string and then stops.**

**/k : Carries out the command specified by string and continues.**

```
proc.Arguments = "/K "+ "ipconfig" ;
```

more info: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 4):

Use `/K` instead of `/C`.

```
proc.Arguments = "/K " + "ipconfig";
```

You can see a list of command line switches [here](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)

> /C     Run Command and then terminate
>
> /K     Run Command and then return to the CMD prompt.
>             This is useful for testing, to examine variables